# install ssl certificate on nginx when provided with private key, CA and ssl certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, vps, private-key

I purchased SSL certificate from a certain hoster and I got these 4 files

```
> SSL Certificate:
> CSR:
> Private Key:
> CA Certificate:
```

How can I install those files into my VPS server using Nginx? My hoster is not collaborative, and I have to figure out how to install this to my client site. All googling leads me to the normal installation where we generate CSR from my VPS, submit to hoster, get certificates, merge and then fix them with Nginx, but for this case, I'm totally confused
Any help, I will appreciate

Comment: How to use a certificate for nginx is well documented on many places. Often also the sellers of SSL certificates themselves provide such documentation, for example [here](https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/nginx-ssl-installation/). Given the amount of information available, it is unclear what your specific problem is.

Comment: based on the link you share, which amongst those 4 files given are intermediate.crt,  domain_name.crt, and which one is domain_name.key ? My problem is to identify which file to include in nginx configuration and which one not to include @SteffenUllrich

Comment: The private key is the `domain_name.key`. The certificate is `domain_name.crt`, the CA certificate is `intermediate.crt`. The CSR is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you receive your server certificate and private key you would place those in a directory on your web server then target those files inside of your config file. This can be a full path or a path relative to the .conf file where this server is configured. 
[Configure HTTPS server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

```
server {
  listen              443 ssl;
  server_name         www.example.com;
  ssl_certificate     /path/to/your/file.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/file.key;
}
```

Depending on your certificate provider they should have also given you a file that contains the CA chains necessary for browsers to validate your certificate. I'm guessing the file you call **CA Certificate** is that file. You will need to combine both your server certificate and the CA certificate, then target that file inside of your nginx conifiguration.
Example:

```
cat SSL_Certificate CA_Certificate > website.crt
server {
      listen              443 ssl;
      server_name         www.example.com;
      ssl_certificate     /path/to/your/website.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/website.key;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried closely to follow your guidance including the link you have shared as follows.  I have treated SSL Certificate AS file.crt , THEN, I have treated the Private Key file as my file.key , THEN I restarted Nginx, and it works BUT the browser says (www.example.com sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR). Then I decided to use CA, combined file.crt with my CA certificate to create another file that I named chain.crt and edit Nginx conf to replace file.crt with chain.crt but still after restarting Nginx and refresh my browser, I got the same error...

Comment: Anything in the logs?  It might be worth looking at the permissions on those files.  Also, try `openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443` and see if there's any useful info there.